# Visual Basic string to click a button on a page

Tags: vba, web-scraping, vbscript, automation, screen-scraping

The tasks is supposed to be simple: Go to a URL and click a button, which downloads an excel file. If it's a wiki page or google or anything like that I can navigate to the site ok and do there whatever I want, but the problem is when i try to browse our company's internal sites.

I tried this VB script:

```
Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://thisithewebsitesurl"
WScript.Sleep (9000)
With IE.Document
.getElementByID("BUTTON_TOOLBAR_2_btn1_acButton").Click
End With
```

But got

> "The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable 'IE.Document'"

EDIT:

I also tried to ran a code in VBA, which worked fine for Wiki and google. Sadly no luck with my web site and i get the same error message. Might be because it's a company's website and it's somehow protected from "automatic" behavior ?

```
Sub BrowseIE()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://abw.xxxxx"

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop
Set HTMLInput = IE.Document.getElementsById("iwaloginbtn")
HTMLInput.Click

End Sub
```

The HTML looks like this :

```
<a id="BUTTON_TOOLBAR_2_btn1_acButton" ct="B" title="Excel" st="" href="javascript:void(0);" ti="0" tabindex="0" class="urBtnStd" ocl="sapbi_page.sendCommandArray([['GUID','11',0],['NOUILOCK','X',0],['BI_COMMAND_TYPE','ABSTRACT',0]],event);" onkeydown="ur_Button_keypress(event);" onclick="ur_Button_click(event);"
```

I've tried multiple solutions from Stackoverflow and elsewhere, but there's always something wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to google for a piece code that does what you want. Because, and no offense, it does not look like you have much of an idea of how VBScript works. You claim to have tried VBScript in Chrome, which is simply impossible. What you meant to say is probably that you managed to launch chrome when you used `wsh.Run someURL`. Spoiler-alert: that's a dead-end.

The IE route is possible, although it should be noted that IE is deprecated. Just google some more, plenty of examples out there. And it helps to at least get a basic understanding of vbscript.

Comment: No offence taken, you are correct - i am looking for a piece of code which will do what i won't. No surprise here, considering the title of my post and the nature of this forum. And all forums in general.
Cheers for advice not to use Chrome. There are plenty of solutions for IE, however none of them work for me. Details are listed in my first post. 
I THINK, that maybet some libraries have been disabled on my working machine?
Following Wise Owl's VBA tutorial i get run-time error 430: "Class Does not support Automation or does not support expected interface." Thoughts? Besides googling.

Comment: `The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable` happens way before you get to click any buttons. Are you sure your firewall is not blocking you? Can you open `https://thisithewebsitesurl` in IE manually?

Comment: @PiotrChmurzynski This isn't a traditional *"forum"*, don't think of it as such that is the first mistake many people make then get frustrated when their question is closed and don't understand why. Please take five minutes to view the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting questions.

Comment: @GSerg. Yes, there are no problems when I try to open the site manually. Whether in IE or Chrome.

Comment: Can you share the URL to have a look and test?

Comment: @YasserKhalil Unfortunately I may not. But even if I could, this is a company's internal web which i think one can only access from a work laptop with the company's VPN. The laptop where I'm trying to use this script is a work laptop with a company's VPN. I can access the website manually without problems. I can also browse to it from a script. The problem starts when i try to perform any scripted actions once I'm there.

Comment: Have you tried using Selenium?

Comment: Selenium requires adding a chromium driver to PATH, which I can't do without admin rights to my work laptop.